# Domain level admin Permission In Magento 2 Backend

Tags: magento2, multidomain, multisite

I have experience with magento for a long time, When creating multiple domain sites, i always thought Magento 2 has, by default, the option to have a specific admin for each domain (that's what I sold). I'm working on 2.3.5 and i dont see it anywhere, I'm missing something? is hidden somewhere? maybe 2.4.1 have it? it it doesn't, please advise if there is a extension for this already developed

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla Magento Community it is not possible to restrict access to some Magento websites for some admin users.
However, Magento Commerce has this functinality (Role Scopes):

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html

I have tried some extensions in the past for this but have no really good experience with them and they tend to cause more problems than they solve, the situation might have gotten better now, I would recommend starting with browsing the Magento marketplace.